# Translating とする彼を

Tags: particle-と

I'm looking at Lake & Ura's *Learn to Read in Japanese* page 37-102

> 危険な場所に行こうとする彼を、みんなが引き止めた。

is translated as

> On the "to-a-dangerous-place-he-will-try-to-go" him, everyone detained.

in the book, and

> Everyone stopped him trying to go to a dangerous place

by Google Translate. The google translation seems a lot more idiomatic, but I can't tell if it's correct because I don't understand the second half of the first clause: "とする彼を"

Comment: Wow, for once Google Translate's translation is more comprehensible than a textbook's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simpler first you can cut out the first part of the sentence.

彼をみんなが引き止めた。 This is simply "everyone stopped him"

The first part we cut out is all just describing the "him" that everyone stopped.

the he who 危険な場所に行こうとする.

In English we'd just say something like "they stopped him from going to a dangerous place." Or "They stopped him, as he was trying to go to a dangerous place." might be closer.

Anyway, (危険な場所に行こうとする) is basically one big adjective describing 彼.